# can't use new color.new function to set transparency if the variable has an expression

Tags: pine-script

so in the new pinescript transp will not be supported, i am refactoring some code and have replaced it with e.g "color = color.new(colorWhite, 60)" when color is a simple variable it works:

example of working variable:
colorWhite = #ffffff

now the problem begin when variable is the result of an expression

example of variable i'm trying to use:
rsiColor = rsi <= rsiOversold ? colorGreen : rsi >= rsiOverbought ? colorRed

if i use the same method on this one it gives me no errors but it breaks the whole script

also when the color is not specified and i just need to apply transparency the .new function is a PITA

plz help

Comment: For now I can see only error that you forgot to add `expr3` in the second ternar. 

`rsiColor = rsi <= rsiOversold ? colorGreen : rsi >= rsiOverbought ? colorRed` : colorSomething